# how to set memcached auto start when linux start?

Tags: shell, memcached

I installed memcached in ubuntu,and i want to set memcache to auto start when system started,but i something go wrong!
I create a shell script named memcached in /etc/init.d/,here is my code:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# processname: memcached
# config: /etc/sysconfig/memcached

# Source function library - for other linux
#. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
# Source function library - for suse linux

#load the public function used by all shell scripts
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PORT=11211
USER=root
#最大连接数，根据实际需求修改
MAXCONN=1024
#最大内存量，单位M
CACHESIZE=128
OPTIONS=""

if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/memcached ];then
  . /etc/sysconfig/memcached
fi

# Check that networking is up.
if [ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ]
then
then
  exit 0
fi

RETVAL=0
prog="memcached"
start () {
  echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
  # insure that /usr/local/memcached has proper permissions
  chown $USER /usr/local/memcached
  /usr/local/memcached/bin/memcached -d -p $PORT -u $USER  -m $CACHESIZE -c $MAXCONN -P /usr/local/memcached/memcached.pid $OPTIONS
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/memcached
}
stop () {
  echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
  killproc memcached
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] ; then
  rm -f /var/lock/subsys/memcached
  rm -f /usr/local/memcached/memcached.pid
  fi
}

restart () {
  stop
  start
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
  start
  ;;
  stop)
  stop
  ;;
  status)
  status memcached
  ;;
  restart|reload)
  restart
  ;;
  condrestart)
  [ -f /var/lock/subsys/memcached ] && restart || :
  ;;
  *)
  echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload|condrestart}"
  exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

then i add execute permission to this file,asd when i execute

```
chkconfig --add memcached
```

the problem occurs,it says:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K20acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-stop' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'rsyslog' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-manager' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
.......
/sbin/insserv failed, exit code 1
memcached                 0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `chkconfig` is more of a Redhat-ism, which you *can* install on Ubuntu (and looks like you have). However, it looks like many of the dependencies (i.e. startup scripts) here have been migrated away from this onto Upstart and so using this system will be difficult at best.

For Ubuntu, you might want to [create an upstart script](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) instead. Note though that recently Ubuntu have [decided](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316) to move to [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) in the future.

Alternatively, look into a more Ubuntu-friendly `sysv-rc-conf` (see [this Askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu) for more details).